# How to find out the quality of the video?

Tags: audio, video, video-streaming

If I do have multiple URL links for videos or audios, how can I determine which one has the best quality. Is there a header information, which tells me about the quality of the video - even the content type is different?

**Example for Videos:**

- The content-type of the first URL is: `video/3gpp`
- The content-type of the second URL is: `video/mp4`

**Example for Audios:**

- The content-type of the first URL is: `audio/3gpp`
- The content-type of the second URL is: `audio/webm`

Is it possible to compare them based on quality - which I get from the header information? Im asking this for URLs with only Audio and URLs with only Video (audio and video).

Comment: Do you have any example?

Comment: Possibly you can check by going to the terminal/command line and running `curl` like this: `curl -I [url of video]` and the headers *should* tell you all kinds of details. But without knowing the URL you are testing against, this question is too broad.

Comment: @Biswapriyo Unfortunately not. They are all internal videos, which are accessed by URL.

Answer (score 2):

The HTTP headers are unlikely to tell you anything more than the video or audio container format. But most modern video and audio container formats can have any number of different qualities of video or audio stored inside them. To know what quality the actual data inside the container file is, you'll have to begin downloading the file and look at the internal headers of the file (not the HTTP headers).

That said, since your example includes 3GPP HTTP content-types, I would **guess** that those are lower-quality than the MPEG-4 and WebM versions, because 3GPP video was originally designed as low-bitrate video that could easily stream across slow (by today's standards) early 3G networks to flip phones with tiny low-res screens from like 2006.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is just extension of [Spiff's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1390291/726810) with real examples.

For example, here I choose this video [Running your First Docker Container in Azure](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/DevOps-Lab/Running-your-First-Docker-Container-in-Azure) from Channel9 MSDN. It has four file formats of that video. What I did? Answer: Use `curl --head` to show ONLY header of that HTTP/GET request which contains the Content-Type and Content-Length. Then download those. Use `ffmpeg -i` to show the downloaded video file encoding information (only important sections are provided below). Here are the three of them:

1. Low quality MP4:

```
$> curl --head "https://sec.ch9.ms/ch9/7a84/8269395e-c022-4672-8b43-3cf1b5d57a84/jay-gordon-docker-in-azure.mp4"
Content-Length: 42,102,244
Content-Type: video/mp4

$> ffmpeg -i jay-gordon-docker-in-azure.mp4
Duration: 00:17:54.05, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 313 kb/s
Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 640x360, 210 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 30k tbn, 59.94 tbc (default)
Metadata:
  handler_name    : ?Mainconcept Video Media Handler
Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 96 kb/s (default)
Metadata:
  handler_name    : #Mainconcept MP4 Sound Media Handler
```

2. Mid Quality MP4:

```
$> curl --head "https://sec.ch9.ms/ch9/7a84/8269395e-c022-4672-8b43-3cf1b5d57a84/jay-gordon-docker-in-azure_mid.mp4"
Content-Length: 129,621,802
Content-Type: video/mp4

$> ffmpeg -i jay-gordon-docker-in-azure_mid.mp4
Duration: 00:17:54.05, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 965 kb/s
Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720, 828 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 30k tbn, 59.94 tbc (default)
Metadata:
  handler_name    : ?Mainconcept Video Media Handler
Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
Metadata:
  handler_name    : #Mainconcept MP4 Sound Media Handler
```

3. High Quality MP4:

```
$> curl --head "https://sec.ch9.ms/ch9/7a84/8269395e-c022-4672-8b43-3cf1b5d57a84/jay-gordon-docker-in-azure_high.mp4"
Content-Length: 385,374,160
Content-Type: video/mp4

$> ffmpeg -i jay-gordon-docker-in-azure_high.mp4
Duration: 00:17:54.05, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 2870 kb/s
Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1920x1080, 2701 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 30k tbn, 59.94 tbc (default)
Metadata:
  handler_name    : ?Mainconcept Video Media Handler
Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 160 kb/s (default)
Metadata:
  handler_name    : #Mainconcept MP4 Sound Media Handler
```

Compare these three command output. As the quality increase Content-Length increase thus bitrate of audio and video. So, it may be possible to *speculate* the video quality from Content-Length in `curl --head` command but HTTP header does not provide full video encoding. To know more about the video encoding, one has to download the file. Only URL can not provide those information.

- Used tools:

  - [curl](https://curl.haxx.se/)
  - [aria2](https://aria2.github.io/)
  - [ffmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org/)